# Проверка загруженных файлов в Golang

Tags: golang

Пишу веб-приложение и нужно проверять корректность загруженных фотографий. Как [загружать](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/04.5.html) понятно, но как проверить то, что файл является действительно фотографией?

Посмотрел на [magicmime](https://github.com/rakyll/magicmime), но это биндинг к libmagic, а хотесь средствами Go проверять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно всего лишь проверить, является ли файл действительно изображением определённого формата, можно просто попытаться декодировать файл:

```
_, format, err := image.Decode(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("can't decode file: %v", err)
}

if format != "jpeg" {
    log.Fatalf("file is not jpeg")
}
```

Comment: С таким подходом он будет весь файл загружать в память, нельзя по первым, например, 100 кб проверить?

Comment: Для [JPEG](https://golang.org/pkg/image/jpeg/#DecodeConfig) и [PNG](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#DecodeConfig) есть функция `DecodeConfig`, которая не считывает весь файл, но тогда "злоумышленник" сможет составить такой файл, который в начале валиден, а далее - мусор или что-то вреднее.

Answer (score 0):

использовать strings.HasPrefix и пройтись по  известным заголовкам. Но  конечно, эта проверка ничем не лучше  DecodeConfig